# How do I upgrade to Mathematica 10.1?

Tags: software-installation

Is there a separate repository I need to add?
Has the 10.1 update been released for the raspberry pi platfrom?

Answer (score 2):

10.1 has not yet been release for Raspberry Pi. If you've recently done a `sudo apt-get update`, you can check the most recent release version with:

```
apt-cache policy wolfram-engine
```

This currently returns:

```
wolfram-engine:
  Installed: 10.0.2+2015020304
  Candidate: 10.0.2+2015020304
  Version table:
 *** 10.0.2+2015020304 0
        500 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

which confirms:

1. 10.0.2 is current release; and
2. it's in the standard *archive.raspberrypi.org* repo.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a separate repository (there used to be but I think it was deprecated some time in late 2014).

If and when Mathematica is updated you may upgrade a Raspbian system with

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wolfram-engine
```